# Microsoft graph, upload a large file (> 100 MB) with the Python SDK

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

I want to upload large file to a Sharepoint folder in Python. I'm using the [msgraph-sdk-python](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python).

I found an example of what I want to do on the [microsoft graph documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/large-file-upload?tabs=PHP) but not in Python.

On this link, there is an example in PHP, it's really close to what I can do in Python. But I can't seem to get my hands on a class like LargeFileUploadTask().

Also I have found a [Python example of upload session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/attachment-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=python) (on the calendar section)  in python but I dont understand how I'm supposed to send my file with this technic.

[A similar issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python/issues/640) has been opened on the project Github repo and [a work around](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python/issues/276) for this problem is proposed. But no real solution to this problem.

> I understand that I need to create an UploadSession object and use it like in the PHP snippet but I really don't understand how to do it.

This is the code I use, based on the work around on the github issue, but the upload is really slow

```
async def _upload_video(self, video: Video) -> None:
    try:
        if not video.is_downloaded or not video.is_processed:
            raise Exception("Video not downloaded or not processed")

        print(f"Uploading video {video.title}")

        request_body = DriveItem()
        request_body.name = video.title
        request_body.file = File()
        result = await self.app_client.drives.by_drive_id(self.drive_id).items.by_drive_item_id(
            self.trans_video_id).children.post(body=request_body)

        with open(video.path, "rb") as f:
            data = f.read()
        print(f"Uploading data to {video.title}")
        await self.app_client.drives.by_drive_id(self.drive_id).items.by_drive_item_id(result.id).content.put(
            body=data)
        print(f"Video {video.title} has been uploaded")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: 100 millibits (mb) or 100 megabytes (MB)? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte

Comment: 100 megabytes..